# Imagen no guardada bien en BD php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy migrando a usar funciones, inserta la imagen pero no la recupera, en el anterior código normal inserta y recupera;cabe decir que la imagen fue recogida asi:

```
$foto1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string(base64_decode($_REQUEST['foto1']));
```

Codigo con funcion:

```
<?php
function registrarDocente($nombre1,$apellidop1,$apellidom1,$correo1,$sexo1,$foto1, $codigo1,$password,$doc,$telefono1,$fecha1,$tdocumento1,$documento1){
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios nombres,apellidop,apellidom,foto,correo,tdoc,ndoc,user,password,tipo,genero,ntelefono,fnacimiento) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt-> bind_param('sssssiiisiiis',$nombre1,$apellidop1,$apellidom1,$foto1,$correo1,$tdocumento1,$documento1,$codigo1,$password,$doc,$sexo1,$telefono1,$fecha1);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $data[]=array('mensaje'=> 'Docente registrado con exito');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
}
?>
```

Codigo anterior:

```
if ($verificacion1=='1D') {
//Sentencia, insertar registro.
if (mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usuarios (nombres,apellidop,apellidom,foto,correo,tdoc,ndoc,user,password,tipo,genero,ntelefono,fnacimiento) 
    VALUES ('".$nombre1."','".$apellidop1."','".$apellidom1."','".$foto1."','".$correo1."','".$tdocumento1."','".$documento1."','".$codigo1."','".$password."',
    '".$doc."','".$sexo1."','".$telefono1."','".$fecha1."')")){
    $data[]=array('mensaje'=> 'Docente registrado con exito');
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    $data[]=array('mensaje'=> 'Docente no registrado');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Que error te aparece? Como Buena practica es mas recommendable que al momento de ingresar la imagen, la muevas hacia una carpeta, esto para que no se haga tan pesada tu base de datos, dejando solo el nombre de la imagen y su extension en la base de datos

un ejemplo a lo que me refiero es el siguiente:

```
$thumb_guardada = $_POST['thumb-guardada'];
$thumb = $_FILES['thumb'];
        if (empty($thumb['name'])) {
            $thumb = $thumb_guardada;
        } else {
            $archivo_subido = 'images/' . $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
            $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
        }

        $errores = '';
        $success = '<li>Los datos se reflejaran cuando vuelvas a iniciar sesion</li>';

            try {
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empleos', 'root', '');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE userslog SET thumb = :thumb WHERE id = :id');

            if (!empty($errores)) {

                $statement->execute(array(
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':thumb' => $thumb
                ));
```

thumb guardad la uso en un input tipo `hidden` donde traigo el nombre de la iamgen en caso de que el usuario no la cambie